# If $f(x)= \lim\limits_{n \to\infty} n(x^{1/n} - 1)$ then $f(xy)=\cdots$

Tags: limits

If $f(x)= \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} n(x^{1/n} - 1)$ then $f(xy)=\cdots$

> A) $f(x)+f(y)$
>   B) $f(x)/f(y)$
>   C) $f(x)-f(y)$
>   D) $f(x)f(y)$

Comment: Two of these options can be eliminated immediately because they are not symmetric in $x$ and $y$ even though $f(xy)$ is. A third can be eliminated by noting that $f(1) = 0$.

Comment: Can u please give me the procedure? As I am getting same answer in two options

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: And one option can be discarded by considering $y=1$.

Comment: You can do this directly without any guesswork. Write $$n\{(xy)^{1/n} - 1\} = n\{x^{1/n}y^{1/n} - y^{1/n} + y^{1/n} - 1\} = y^{1/n}\cdot n(x^{1/n} - 1) + n(y^{1/n} - 1)$$ and on taking limit as $n \to \infty $ we get $f(xy) = f(x) + f(y)$. Also note that the limit $f(x)$ exists only when $x > 0$ so that the above equation holds when $x, y $ are positive.

Answer (score 2):

Two of these can be eliminated immediately because they are not symmetric in $x$ and $y$, even though $f(xy)$ is. The third can be eliminated by noting that $f(1) = 0$. More reasoning is required, but this gets you to an answer that makes sense.

Comment: You still need to show $f$ is not zero everywhere to eliminate the third option right?

Comment: Of course. I ninja edited the last line in for that reason. That said, it's easy to see that $f\not\equiv 0$ since otherwise there would be two answers and it's a multiple choice question :P

Comment: It could be a multiple choice question with not necessarily only one correct answer :P

Comment: Haha very good point.

Answer (score 1):

Let $t=\frac{1}{n}$. Then $f(x)=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{x^t-1}{t}=\ln{x}$.